# What do the empty portraits do?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In Cascade Kingdom, there is an empty portrait hidden behind the waterfall. When walking up to it, Cappy wonders to himself what the portrait might be used for.

[image]

I later found a second empty portrait in Sand Kingdom on the side of a tower.

[image]

What do these empty portraits do? Is there some way to interact with them?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, portraits are warps to other worlds, usually to snag a power moon. At this time I'm not sure what activates a portrait (previously I thought you had to beat or visit a world to unlock it).

Comment: They are definitely portals, and you don't have to beat the world on the other side to activate them. I went through the portal in the lower screenshot of the question, and I haven't even started the world on the other side. I had finished the sand kingdom before I found it though.

Comment: I'm not sure what the pre-req to unlock them is in that case, the game is never very forthcoming about it. Would appreciate a tip. I finished all the worlds today, so will be going through them one by one and finding the specific details of each world.

Comment: @Adeese I can confirm that the Sand portrait let me preview New Donk City before I had unlocked the level. The Cascade portrait is still empty however.

Comment: Definitely don't need to beat the area to use the picture.  I got to Luncheon Kingdom in one of the earlier worlds (whatever the first water one is), and got to Mushroom Kingdom early as well.

Comment: That's reasonable, but then what _is_ the unlock condition? In the mean time I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe you have to beat the story in the current world to use the portrait? Or maybe certain portraits unlock at certain points in the game? When I visited Cascade for the first time I found an empty portrait, but I never checked back in on it until after I beat the game.

Comment: @Seiyria Cascade’s portrait was still empty for me after clearing Sand Kingdom, while New Donk City’s portrait unlocked after the first story mission. (Saving Pauline’s city)

Comment: Here's my theory: If the portrait leads to a part of the world that is isolated from the rest (e.g. New Donk City and Luncheon), the portrait is unlocked as soon as you've collected all the main Moons of the world you're in. If the portrait leads to a part of the world from where you can access the rest, the portrait is only unlocked after you first land on that world. It's just my theory though and needs to be proven first.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro. In my case, New Donk City's portrait unlocked as soon as I got rid of the ice in the Sand Kingdom. I hadn't even reached New Donk City yet.

Comment: @Nolonar Of course, some are not as isolated as they were intended to be...

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden portraits, which are portals to a hidden place in the game.

For the hidden portraits to unlock you usually need to beat the Kingdom Boss, or at least that's what these two articles say.

http://www.accelerated-ideas.com/news/super-mario-odyssey-all-painting-locations-warp-gates.aspx

http://www.gamesradar.com/super-mario-odyssey-portrait-warp-hole-location-guide/

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate that articles information is.  For example;  I'm pretty convinced that the portal in the Lake Kingdom took me to the Luncheon kingdom, not the Sand Kingdom.  I also went to the Lake Kingdom after the Wooded (which it seems as though in the first article they went the other order).  I don't think I found a portrait in the Wooded Kingdom.